# run jsf application with myeclipse and jboss server

Tags: java, jsf, jboss

I develop simple jsf login application,that use icefaces component but, when I tries to run it in jboss server I got following error.

> Can't find TLD for location
>   [`http://java.sun.com/jsf/core`]. JAR
>   containing the TLD may not be in the
>   classpath
>
> Can't find TLD for location [`http://java.sun.com/jsf/html`]. JAR
>   containing the TLD may not be in the
>   classpath

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the JSF implementation JAR's in the classpath. As of now there are two choices: [Sun Mojarra](http://javaserverfaces.dev.java.net) and [Apache MyFaces](http://myfaces.apache.org). I'd recommend to pick Mojarra. You'll get two JAR files: `jsf-api.jar` and `jsf-impl.jar`. Put them in the classpath of the webapplication in question and this problem should go away. The `/WEB-INF/lib` folder is by default covered by the webapp's classpath, so just drop those JAR's in that folder and redeploy.

If you for instance already have done it, then there's likely means of classpath pollution with different versioned JAR files and/or a classpath cluttered with loose JAR file contents. You'll need to cleanup it.

Comment: Thank for responding,

I have included both jar file at /WEB-INF/lib now I get following error

18:53:51,625 ERROR [[/webtest]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config.JBossJSFConfigureListener
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null

Comment: Thus in other words, JBoss already ships with a JSF implementation in the classpath. Well, the initial exception complaining about the missing TLD can then only be caused by a greatly messed up classpath/configuration. Verify if you understand the phenomenon "classpath" and cleanup it. If in vain, I would recommend to cleanup everything and redo based on the provided tutorials/documentations.